# implementing sendEnrollmentEmail with onEnrollmentLink

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code accepts an email from the user and calls a method `createNewUser` on the server.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'createNewUser': function (email) {
    const userId = Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: 'dummy'});
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
  }
});
```

I get an email with this link

> http://localhost:3000/#/enroll-account/6I-arlzO2Kpz4N4KOtb_8UOO1dR_YrKbparLjsF9PNd

How can I use `Accounts.onEnrollmentLink()` to show a template I made to accept a password, because right now it just take me to http://localhost:3000/#, BTW I am not using the route package.

```
<template name="passwordCreate">
<h5>Please create a password for your account</h5>
  <input type="text" name="pswrd1" placeholder="Enter a password">
  <input type="text" name="pswrd2" placeholder="Re enter the password">
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use some kind of routing - preferably iron:router or flow-router.

So if you use iron:router and define a route "passwordCreate" for the above template, you may call

```
Router.go('\passwordCreate?token="+token);
```

in the callback function provided to Accounts.onEnrollmentLink().

You can extract this token from the Router.params which you can then use with Accounts.resetPassword() as specified in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-onEnrollmentLink).

Comment: My question is mainly about how to code in the method `Accounts.onEnrollmentLink()` i.e. where to place/use it and how the syntax look. ;)